# Achieve geofencing using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement geofencing through xamarin.forms. First i have started my work in iOS then i found a library i.e. CoreLocation, in this i am using CLCircularRegion class for making virtual boundary.

```
CLCircularRegion region = new CLCircularRegion(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(+28.5003615,+77.0718658), 1.0, "MDS");
```

But i am not sure about the central points(latitude,longitude) which is passed in CLLocationCoordinate2D. How can i get exact latitude and longitude of my place and how i can implement geofencing in correct manner in iOS through xamarin.forms.

Comment: You might have a look into [this guide](http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#geolocation) on how to get the user location from within Xamarin.Forms. Concerning the geofencing part of your question: I'm not quite sure what the exact problem is. Don't you simply need to retrieve the location repeatedly and compare it to the virtual circle?

Comment: @Falko Actually i have implemented geofencing according to the document. http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/multitasking/geofencing/ but i am unable to check whether it is working or not?

Comment: I am not sure, the boundary which i have declared is exact or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get exact latitude and longitude of my place

Once you set the Geofencing the device start to track you location to see if you entered the defined fence. You can also use the `MKMapView` to identify and follow the user.

I have put together a small sample [project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xy68a3i6ldd8amx/AAD5amfC5KLlS1SCd0Y0aWw_a?dl=0) couple of weeks ago to demonstrate the Geofencing in iOS

> how i can implement geofencing in correct manner in iOS through xamarin.forms.

The Geofencing is platform-specific code that you cannot really abstract out in shared project. Instead, you can use [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access the method/events from iOS project to Shared project

Comment: I saw your code, It was very helpful to me but in CLLocationCoordinate2D you are using two co ordinate which is hard coded.Can you please tell me how is it defined and how can i find these coordinates for me?